# Computer animated short film about an AI hologram enslaved on a space station, rescued by mercenaries

Tags: story-identification, short-film

I once saw a computer animated short film about an AI hologram that is enslaved in a factory on a space station by some sort of taskmaster. She contacts mercenaries that come to her rescue. The mercenaries fight and then succumb to several waves of robots. Their efforts allow the AI hologram to escape.

I think I saw this in the era before YouTube.

Maybe I discovered it during the earliest days of the Vuze HD Network in the Azureus BitTorrent client.

I don't think there was any spoken dialog.

The holographic avatar of the AI was that of a child rendered in blue and or green tones.

Duration: somewhere between 5 and 15 minutes

Comment: Hi there! That's helpful info already, but just in case, please take a look at [this handy guide on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories to edit in, however minor it may seem. Everything could prove helpful :)